# . Find the dimension of a rectangular piece of a lot that can be covered by 500 meters of barbed wire fence

Tags: optimization

Solve the given problem.

Find the dimension of a rectangular piece of a lot that can be covered by 500 meters of barbed wire fence

Comment: Your question is unclear, as there are a lot of dimensions that can be covered by, say, $100\,\mathrm{m}\times 150\,\mathrm{m}$ or $200\,\mathrm{m}\times 50\,\mathrm{m}$. Please try to clarify your question.

Comment: Are you trying to maximize the area of the rectangular lot?  Besides the fact that you need to proofread/edit your question to remove ambiguity, please also include in your editing what efforts that you have made to solve the problem.